# ¿Por que SO carga lento en la versión móvil?

Tags: soporte, bug, web-móvil

La página de SO carga lento en su versión movil, así como cuando creas una pagina en heroku con dynos gratuitos que después de x tiempo de inactividad los dynos se duermen.

Es algo molesto por que aveces cuando busco algo sobre programación en google, y aparecen resultados de preguntas de SO que podrían resolver mis problemas, tarda aproximadamente medio minuto en cargar. Al principio pensé que era mi móvil pero no, ya he probado abrir la pagina de SO en otros dispositivos móviles y se tarda de la misma forma e incluso tarda un poco mas en cargar.

Comment: ¿La web o la app?

Comment: @fedorqui La web

Comment: @fedorqui lo confirmo a mi me pasa lo mismo si dejo de navegar la web durante unos minutos y luego trato de recargarla de nuevo

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo, incluso pensé que era mi dispositivo o mi conexión, hay veces que ni siquiera llega a cargar completa la página

Comment: Si te encuentras dentro de algún proxy probablemente se este bloqueando algún recurso de la página, yo uso comúnmente el navegador en mis dispositivos móviles y es "lento" pero no tarda más de 10 segundos el cargar completamente, el problema que comentas puede deberse a la conexión o a recursos que no se permiten descargar en tu red, saludos.

Comment: @Elenasys quizás sea una restricción sobre la descarga de un recurso, que lo dudo. Además de que solo uso 1.1.1.1 de clouflare

Comment: @Elenasys yo no uso proxy alguno

Comment: @Elenasys creo que el problema proviene de https://traducir.win por que supongo que lo usan directamente, como a una API que traduce de manera instantánea. El caso es que al abrir la pagina de https://traducir.win y tarda de la misma forma que SO. Quizás sea un bug de https://traducir.win que esta afectando a SO directamente

Comment: Como dice @Aprendiz. Lo confirmo, es el sitio de https://traducir.win es el que esta afectando a SO, el sitio me acaba de tirar un **504 Gateway Time-Out**

Comment: Aquí la captura https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdV2Z.png

Comment: traducir.win anduvo con problemas en estos días porque lo cambié de servidor... pero de ninguna forma afecta a SO (es un sistema totalmente independiente)

Comment: dicho sea de paso, nunca vi una página de SO demorar más de 1 segundo... si ven más de eso, deberían reportarlo como bug. No es nada normal. Y por chequear nomas, otros sitios andan perfecto?

Comment: @g3rv4 pero yo anduve navegando por traducir.win y ahí mismo marca el tiempo de carga, aveces que me decía que tardaba 500 ms. Incluso me salio varias veces el error **504**

Comment: como dije, traducir.win anduvo con problemas ayer y hoy. Puede que siga mañana. Sin embargo, eso no puede afectar en absoluto a SO. SO tiene su base de datos de traducciones y al compilar el sitio las traducciones terminan en el dll que sirve el servidor. Como estamos en code freeze, no han habido deploys desde alrededor del 2 de diciembre

Comment: @g3rv4 pero eso no quita el por que SO tarda en cargar en su versión móvil, desde smartphones. :( Por ejemplo ahorita estoy dentro, dejo la pagina abierta y dejo de navegar en ella por unos 5 mins, se congela y tarda aproximadamente de entre 30 o 50 segundos en cargar cuando la refresco o abro una pregunta. Y eso ocurre también si estoy fuera de ella, ya sea que la abra desde google o directamente desde la barra de direcciones

Comment: Además de que no uso proxys, solo uso el VPN 1.1.1.1 de cloudflare pero no lo uso muy seguido ya que me gasta saldo.

Comment: exacto, eso que comentas es MUY raro... nunca vi que demorara más de algunos milisegundos. 30 a 50s es reportable como bug :) sólo quería dejar en claro que el hecho de que traducir esté caído no afecta a SO